# Gstreamer Audio Conference application with UDP Multicast

Tags: audio, udp, gstreamer, audio-streaming, multicast

I'm trying to implement audio conference application with multiple users using gstreamer. I'm sending/receiving raw pcm audio data with UDP Multicast through `237.1.1.1` ip and same port on each device `50004`. Every sender/receiver on network transmit/receive data through this multicast ip and same port. I able to observe every hosts' data packets using network tool.

Gstreamer configuration for sender side:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v autoaudiosrc ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! audio/x-raw, rate=16000, channels=1, format=S16LE ! udpsink host=237.1.1.1 auto-multicast=true port=50004
```

Gstreamer configuration for receiver side:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc multicast-group=237.1.1.1 port=50004 auto-multicast=true loop=false ! rawaudioparse use-sink-caps=false format=pcm pcm-format=s16le sample-rate=16000 num-channels=1 ! queue ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink
```

The problem is, if there are only 2 users, application is working great, no noises, no packet loss, no corruption. But if one more user is connected (3 or more users connected), voice is suddenly starts to jittering/distorted/noisy. Every user can hear others, but too noisy and distorted.

Can you help me what im doing wrong? Is it not possible to play two or more audio data on if they are using same port? Or, do i have to use some audio mixing or encoding technique for streaming two audio data on same port?

Comment: You'll need to actually mix the audio, and you'll also want to do it intelligently... otherwise, the audio conference will just pile up with a bunch of noise anyway.  I'd strongly recommend using something that already exists for this.  Voice conferencing is not new, and these are solved problems that are not trivial to solve yourself.

Comment: @Brad, thanks for answer. Two audio data flows through same ip and port, i mean they are nested. so how do i mix it? How do i differentiate which data is from whom? I think i need to send them to another host from different links, then mix it, and forward it back?